# Is there any way to denote a T! platform type in Kotlin only, without resorting to using Java

Tags: kotlin

Is there any way in pure Kotlin to produce a `T!` type as opposed to `T` or `T?` - in other words, is the `T!` type denotable in Kotlin? These obviously don't work:

```kotlin
val t: T! = ...
fun f(): T! = ...
```

I'm open to (reliable) hacks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would be the use case?

Comment: What's the use of those types they are not safe at any way in null-safe languages.

Comment: @jsamol: Out of fear this would turn into a [XYProblem](http://xyproblem.info/) discussion, I omitted the context :) [(Hint)](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6248)

Comment: @AnimeshSahu: I have a use-case where the type safety doesn't help but rather gets in the way of creating false positives (All types are `T?`) or false negatives (Some types are mostly `T` but in fact, are occasionally `T?`).

Comment: A common solution to that problem is to provide two versions of the method/property - a nullable and a non-nullable - and let the user decide which one to use. See `context`/`requireContext()` in the Android framework.

Comment: A type `T?` encompasses all the same possible values as its non-nullable version `T` _except_ that it also allows null.  So if there's _any_ possibility at all of a null, then it must be `T?`.  If at runtime you want to _assert_ it's not null, you can use `!!`.  Otherwise I'm really struggling to imagine a situation where this would be a good idea.  Platform types are a necessary evil when dealing with Java, to be worked around — not a get-out-of-jail-free card for the type system!

Comment: @KirillRakhman: Interesting, I will give this some thought, thanks!

Comment: @gidds: I agree with you. `T?` is the *correct* type. But it can also turn into an *inconvenient* type. Which is why a ton of people will want me to support `T` as well, when it *mostly* works, despite the occasional false negative it produces... Anyway. :)

Comment: Maybe a possible hack would be to wrap it into a java supplier:

`val t: Int = Supplier<Int> { 1 }.get()`
`val tNullable: Int? = Supplier<Int> { 1 }.get()`

Comment: @tibtof `Supplier#get` doesn't return uncertain type, but `inline fun <reified T> T.unknown() = Function.identity<T>().apply(this)` wil do!

Answer (score 1):

Not currently. There was a proposal for this that was open for a few years and then declined some months after you asked this question: https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/issues/82.